# Trying to change value of time to %r

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, date-format

I am a newb so any help is appreciated. I have a database table with a column that stores event times. I need to change the format of that column to the time with am/pm. I think MySQL said it was with %r. I have no idea how to do this through phpMyAdmin. PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $formatted_date = date("l dS \of F Y h:i:s A", $datevariable_to_beformatted);
> echo $formatted_date
> //A is the modifier for AM/PM, if u want lowercase make it a
> Saturday 26th of January 2006 10:41:22 PM
>
> $formatted_date = gmdate("l dS \of F Y h:i:s A", $datevariable_to_beformatted);
> echo $formatted_date
> //A is the modifier for AM/PM, if u want lowercase make it a
> Saturday 26th of January 2006 10:41:27 PM
>
> SELECT date_format(datecolumn, '%W, %M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p') as formatted_date from date_table
> //%p is the modifier for AM/PM
> 'Saturday, January 26, 2013 @ 10:56 PM'
> ```

Note: In mysql datecolumn will be stored either as a timestamp or datetime.